# Efficiently assigning a new column value based on multiple column conditions in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that contains information about many seller's IDs, and the period they made a sell. I want to create a new column called inactive if they didn't make a sell for the next 6 periods.

Here is the dput of a sample dataset:

```
structure(list(SellerID = c(1, 7, 4, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 
5, 7), Period = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 9, 9, 10, 10)), .Names = c("SellerID", 
"Period"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the dput of my ideal outcome(row 5 has an Inactive of 1 because for that row, sellerID 1 made a sale at Period 2, but his next sale was at period 9 [row 10]. Thus, he was inactive for at least 6 periods and thus we want to record that in order to predict when a seller will be inactive):

```
structure(list(SellerID = c(1, 7, 4, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 
5, 7), Period = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 9, 9, 10, 10), Inactive = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("SellerID", 
"Period", "Inactive"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried solving this problem using a nest-for loop approach but my dataset is very large and it will take a very long time to run (about 200,000 rows). I also tried my approach on the sample dataset, but it seems to not work. Here is my approach below:

```
full.df$Inactive <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(full.df)){
  temp = subset(full.df, SellerID = unique(full.df$SellerID[i]))
  for(j in 1:(nrow(temp) -1)){
    if(temp$Period[j+1] - temp$Period[j] <6)
      temp$Inactive[j] <-0
    else
      temp$Inactive[j] <-1
  }
  full.df[rownames(full.df) %in% rownames(temp), ]$Inactive <- temp$Inactive
}
```

The output from the dummy dataset, using my approach puts a 0 in all the rows in "Inactive" except the last row is NA. Here is the dput of the output that I got:

```
structure(list(SellerID = c(1, 7, 4, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 
5, 7), Period = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 9, 9, 10, 10), Inactive = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA)), .Names = c("SellerID", 
"Period", "Inactive"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Use `dput` to share sample data and your attempt at solving this.

Comment: I have edited my post to describe my attempt of solving this. Unfortunately, I cannot share sample data because the data is sensitive and I have signed a confidentiality contract.

Comment: you can create a dummy sample data and explain your problem on that because im still lost at the logic.

Comment: I created the dummy sample data. Please let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: Try `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, Inactive := +(c(diff(Period), 0) > 6), by = SellerID]` (if `df` is your data set). Or using Base R- this should work too `with(df, ave(Period, SellerID, FUN = function(x) +(c(diff(x), 0) > 6)))`

Comment: if i got your logic right then shouldn't seller with id 4  will be inactive. he has not made a sale in next 6 period starting at 3.

Comment: Yes, Chirayu, you are correct. I need to account for that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming 1 things here. Max range of period variable is 12.

Here is the logic: You order the data frame. Then you append 12 to the end of the list and take a difference. This would also categorise seller 3 who is inactive withing the range of 7 days.

```
df_s=df[with(df, order(SellerID, Period)),]
g=split(df$Period, df$SellerID)
l=lapply(g, function(x) c(x,12) )
j=lapply(l, diff)
u=unlist(j, use.names = F)
df_s$ind=ifelse(u>=7,1,0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Chirayu for answering this and guiding me on the general conduct of posting to stackoverflow. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `R --vanilla`

```
# your input dataframe
d <- structure(list(SellerID = c(1, 7, 4, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 
5, 7), Period = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 9, 9, 10, 10)), .Names = c("SellerID", 
"Period"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")

# your wanted output
o <- structure(list(SellerID = c(1, 7, 4, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 
5, 7), Period = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 9, 9, 10, 10), Inactive = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("SellerID", 
"Period", "Inactive"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")

# 6 steps solution, step by step using vanilla R
# step1. - add tmp key for final sorting
d$tmp.key <- seq_len(nrow(d))
# step 2. - split by individual seller id
d.tmp <- split(d,f=d$SellerID)
# step 3. - add inactive column to individual sellers
d.tmp <- lapply(d.tmp,
    function(x){
       # Below as.numeric is optional
       # it may stay logical as well.
       # Also sorting by Period (not used here)
       # should be done (I am asuming it is sorted.)
       x$Inactive <- as.numeric(c(diff(x$Period) >= 6,FALSE))
       x
       })
# step 4. - assemble again individual sellers back into one data.frame
d <- do.call(rbind,d.tmp)
# step 5. - sort to original order using temp.key
d <- d[order(d$tmp.key),c("SellerID","Period","Inactive")]
# step 6. - rename rows according the row order
rownames(d) <- NULL

# here I am just comparing with your wanted ideal
> identical(d,o)    
[1] TRUE
```

For data.frame with 1 000 000 lines and 1 seller the runtime will be more or less 1 second on normal PC.